# LibGDX - Background service for network requests / push notifications

Tags: android, ios, networking, push-notification, libgdx

I am building a game in LibGDX for Android and iOS. We would like it to have a background service that occasionally requests information from a server, and pushes a notification depending on the data received (such as messages, updates, etc..)

I have searched around but haven't really found anything helpful, mainly because I know very little about networking and find it quite confusing.

This service will use an already existing server, APIs and Database that my project partner is managing. Basically the game will have an internal messaging service, we have already tested this to work within the game using Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest, but we would like it to automatically notify users of new messages when the game is not open.

I have read a few people suggest Parse.com for similar requirements, but unfortunately I can't wrap my head around it. Would this work for me? Do I need to host and store the data within Parse or can I use another existing server?

What options do I have?

Thanks in advance.